# can't select from one table on a postgresql database via pyodbc - how to debug

Tags: python, postgresql, pyodbc

I have a postgresql database containing some tables made by drupal, and others I've made myself.  And then I have a python api, using pyodbc, to query the database.

There's just one table, that I can't select from via pyodbc.  If I print the query and paste it into pgadminIII, then it gives the expected result, and if I change the table in the python code it gives the correct result.

The query is

```
select id from a_company where name = 'somename'
```

with result

```
7
8
9
```

etc (50 rows of int ids)

My python code is

```
sql = """select id from a_company where name = 'somename'"""
curs = self._connection.cursor()
sql = self._ConvertToPostGres(sql) #drops [] etc, as the initial code was for MSSQL
curs.execute(sql)
f = curs.fetchall()
```

The call via pyodbc returns

```
None
```

(I can select from other tables using the same connection, so the connection string doesn't matter?)

My best guess is that this is a permissions problem, and that I've done something daft with this particular table.

Can anyone suggest how to debug this?

Create table via pgadmin:

```
-- Table: a_company

-- DROP TABLE a_company;

CREATE TABLE a_company
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('a_company_id_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying,
  abn character varying,
  url character varying,
  anzsic character varying(5),
  address character varying,
  area integer,
  sell_equipment boolean,
  recycling_provider boolean,
  monthly_matches boolean,
  user_id bigint,
  latitude double precision,
  longitude double precision,
  geography geography,
  CONSTRAINT a_company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_a_company_a_anzsic_codes FOREIGN KEY (anzsic)
      REFERENCES a_anzsic_codes (code) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE a_company
  OWNER TO aspire;

-- Index: fki_a_company_aspire_a_codes

-- DROP INDEX fki_a_company_aspire_a_codes;

CREATE INDEX fki_a_company_aspire_a_codes
  ON a_company
  USING btree
  (anzsic COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

If I modify that just enough to change the table name, then I get another table which 'works' properly.  But I changed the id line to just be id serial rather than specifying the sequence.

Comment: What do you get when you run the query on that specific table?

Comment: Please post the python code using pyodbc to initiate the connection, execute the query, and fetch results.

Comment: *"My best guess is that this is a permissions problem"* - So you've made sure that you log in to pgAdmin with the same credentials that your Pythons script uses, and then tried the query there, right?

Comment: @GordThompson: yes, and it works.

Comment: Okay, then please [edit] your question to include **(1)** the CREATE TABLE statement for the table in question (which you can get from pgAdmin), and **(2)** the Python code you are using.

Comment: Thanks for adding the DDL and python code. The `self._ConvertToPostGres(sql)` call sticks out -- where's the source for this function? Feel free to link to the module/library if it's not something you're maintaining.

Comment: @BryanEargle yes, it's the obvious call.  And you're right, something in there is not doing what I think it's supposed to, it's injecting scary sql regarding this table, which is breaking the select call.

Comment: @BryanEargle: if you write an answer, of the 'check what actual sql you are sending' variety, I'll accept it...

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
def load_data(sql, columns):
    sql_data = []

    curs = self._connection.cursor()
    sql = self._ConvertToPostGres(sql)

    try:
        curs.execute(sql)
        rows = curs.fetchall()
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        rows = pd.read_sql(sql, self._connection)

    for row in rows:
        sql_data.append(list(row))

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=sql_data, columns=columns)

    return df


sql = "select id from a_company where name = '{0}'".format(somename)
data = load_data(sql, ['id'])
```